# GLn group action rank

Tags: linear-algebra, group-theory, group-actions

Having the group action $GL(n,K) \times K^{n\times m} \to K^{n\times m} \; (g,A)↦gA  $. The rank is an invariant but not an separating one (why?), how then does the orbits look like? If we acted also from the other side it would be JNF, but so its applying Gauss and for me it seems like only the rank is invariant?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not true that the rank is the only invariant. Note that the kernel of $A$ (or equivalently, the row-space) is also invariant.

Each orbit under this action corresponds to a single [reduced row echelon form matrix](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Row_echelon_form#Reduced_row_echelon_form).

To see that the rank is not an orbit-separating invariant, verify that the matrices
$$
\pmatrix{1&0&0\\0&1&0}, \quad \pmatrix{1&0&0\\0&0&1}
$$
do not lie in the same orbit.

Comment: the two matrices are already in rref and not the same, so assuming the kernel of A is orbit-separting, it follows that they are not in the sameorbit, how do you want to calculate it?

Comment: I'm not telling you to calculate anything. I'm just answering the "why?" regarding rank.

Comment: sure thanks, i just wanted to check that i understand you correctly that the kernel ist orbit-separating

Comment: @user23657 Ah. Yes, the kernel is indeed orbit-separating